# Tkinter w/ Python 2.7.10: Why does my GUI ignore event callbacks until a second event occurs?

Tags: python, tkinter, callback

Currently, I'm working with Python 2.7.10, specifically the Tkinter module, to create a GUI (I'm relatively new to Tkinter). As such, while my goal is to have the GUI print figures with matplotlib, I'm currently just testing the basics with print() to my iPython console (in Spyder). Anyways, a simple version of my code follows:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def run_file(i,f):
    print 'running...'+`i`+', '+`f`

def select_all():
    print('run')    
    run_file(1,97)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x100')

singleframe = tk.Frame(root, bd = 5)
singleframe.pack()

button_fig = tk.Button(singleframe, text='Display All Figures', fg = 
'black', padx = 2, command = select_all)
button_fig.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

**Here's my problem:**
Whenever I click my 'Display All Figures' button, the console remains blank [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6XlB.png), however, if I click it a second time, it displays 'run', and 'running...1, 97' (for my first click), and then displays 'run' (for the second click) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsFHM.png), waiting for me to click it a third time (where it will display the second click's 'running...1, 97' result along with the third click's 'run'). Finally, if I close the program, it will display the 'running...1, 97' from my third click. (My apologies for not including more pictures; somehow I apparently have reputation below 10)

I've been trying to search the web for similar problems; several posts suggest that problems like this occur when too many calculations are occurring, so the GUI freezes up, but my function is very simple, so that seems unlikely; still others suggest the after() function, but I don't see how creating timed delays would help either. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine.. Try running it without spyder.

Comment: When I run the program in linux console it prints `run` and `running...1, 97` on first click and also on subsequent clicks. Did you try out of spyder?

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked, guess it was a really simple solution